# Unable to bypass the TuneUp Utilities disc check

Tags: windows-7

I use Windows 7 on an HP laptop.

I am unable to bypass the TuneUp Utilities disc check. It runs to 55% then stops however long I leave it. If I use safe mode to boot it, it won't load all the files. If I use any other way of entry it won't allow me to stop it from starting by clicking any button within 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like the tuneup utilities is not working correctly. i would try the following in this order:

1. check tune up settings to temp disable and then use windows own tools to test - if no joy....
2. go to start (assuming windows 7) and type in the search "msconfig" and press enter. go to the startup tab and UNTICK anything to do with tuneup. make a note of what you unticked to re-enable later if required. restart PC and attempt disc check again via windows normal tools. if this fixes it then you need to re-install tuneup. - if no joy then.....
3. uninstall tuneup, reboot PC and check again via windows normal tools. - if no joy.....
4. download hirens boot disc and do some tests on you HDD. part magic will do this also but you need a bit of knowledge to use that.

to re-enable tuneup if you had to do step 2 then just do it again except ticking the ones you unticked.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks but I cannot even get to the windows screen as it never finishes disc check so at this moment I cannot delete the program unless it can be done through the cmd prompt